# Pointer Increment in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, increment

I am getting an odd error in a small C program in which I'm trying to learn how to use pointers.

I assumed everything was working because it compiled but when I try to run the code, it says C program has stopped responding. I must be doing something incorrect... Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

int k = 22;
int z = 11;
int *ptr = k;

 printf("%d \n",*ptr);
 ptr++;
 printf("%d \n",*ptr);




    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign address of k not it's value..

```
int *ptr = &k;
```

Also after `ptr++;` `*ptr` would print garbage value(though behavior is undefined)

Comment: Ahh, wow I completely over looked that. However, that brings up another question, isn't that statement saying that the dereferenced pointer(the value) is equal to the address of k? Why isn't it just int ptr = &k ?

Comment: `*ptr` after the increment in this case is undefined so we can't say what it would do, any behavior is possible.

Comment: `int *ptr = &k;` is the same as `int *ptr; ptr = &k;` Don't confuse a declaration from a dereference.

Comment: @Teague "isn't that statement saying that the dereferenced pointer(the value) is equal to the address of k?" -- No, it isn't saying anything remotely like that. Please learn the basics of the subject before posting questions here. "Why isn't it just int ptr = &k" -- Because a variable declared `int` isn't a pointer just because you call it "ptr".

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
int *ptr = k;
```

you are assigning the value of `k` to `ptr` not the address of, so you are missing the address operator(`&`):

```
int *ptr = &k;
           ^
```

`gcc` by default gives the following warning:

> warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

So if you are not seeing a waring then you should enable warnings.

Performing indirection on `ptr` after you increment here:

```
ptr++;
printf("%d \n",*ptr);
               ^
               indirection
```

it is undefined behavior in this case since it will be pointing to one past the last element, since pointers to non-arrays are treated as 1 element arrays for this case as per C99 section `6.5.6` *Additive operators* paragraph *7*.

Comment: @JimBalter Hmm, that is what I explained in the end, I add some more details since I guess it was not clear enough if you missed it.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple to understand pointer, the pointer is a value to store an memory address, and you must always ensure the memory address is avaiable!

so here is the 1st error;

```
int *ptr = k;
```

so 1st you shall assign an valid memory address to the ptr before you use it, correct one shall be

```
int *ptr;
ptr = &K
```

star (*) is use to get the value which is stored in the memory address you assigned. so to increase the value , you shall

```
(*ptr)++
```

instead of

```
ptr++
```

this will increase the address instead of value itself, and you r really unknown what is stored there.

Comment: Well understanding pointers can be not *that simple* in MY opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the help ray_linn. Why I was attempting to do with the ptr++ was to increment the address so that the pointer would then be pointing towards the other declared int z. However, I realized that I need to do ptr-- to make the pointer point at the z address. I'm not exactly sure why that is though. It seems like the z int would have been given an address of bytes greater than the address of k.

Comment: Well. What you expected is based on an assumption that Z is stored just closed the K? but this is no always true. for example when I complied via GCC with O0, use "gcc -S test.c" can make you have an assembly to read. You may see the k is store in -20(%rbp) and z is store in -4(%rbp), ptr is in -16(%rbp). once I change the optimizaiton flag from O0 to O3, things change again. the compiler delete the "z", and pass 22 and some address directly to printf, the variable all disappeared! So unless your claim an array, or your assumption is unbelieable.